# Route a telephone call over tcp/ip via PC (modem?)

Tags: networking, smartphone

I have an office where i have a very old telephone system. I was wondering if I could receive all the calls done to that phone in my smartphone. I have a computer near that phone on 24/7. Is there any way to connect that phone jack to the computer and route every call received over internet and receive it in my phone? How do you think I could achieve this? Thanks!!

Comment: Is this a business telephone system? It may have the ability to ring multiple numbers (including external ones) based on a specific number being dialed. Talk to your IT people about that. If this is just a normal analog line, then you'll need to talk to your Telephone Company, they will likely have a service that provides what you're looking for. What won't work is to plug the line into your computer. Phones don't work that way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you sure that old fashioned "Call Forwarding" isn't an option on your old phone system? Sometimes setting up call forwarding is as easy as dialing *72 and then dialing the number to forward all calls to. Later you can dial *73 to turn it off.

If traditional Call Forwarding from the central office or PBX really isn't an option for you, here's an approach to doing what you asked:

If the phone in your office is a plain old analog telephone, then the hardware you need is called an "FXO" interface for your PC.

If you look hard enough, you can find single-port FXO solutions for US$30-$50.

Most modems are only designed for data, so they don't act as an audio I/O device for your PC. An FXO can detect rings and go off-hook (or go off-hook and then dial) and then start acting as an audio I/O device between the POTS line and your PC, and then go back on-hook at the end of the call.

There's a highly customizable open source VoIP gateway (and much more) software package called Asterisk that you could probably use to gateway the incoming call to whatever device or service you want it to go to.

Caveat lector: I haven't done all this myself, so this is just a possible lead for you to look into. Maybe someone with more DIY VoIP experience can tell me if I'm off my rocker.

Comment: Thanks a lot, i have read a little bit and im going to implement an FXO to route the calls. Im giving support to an institution and it has a very old phone central and i need to forward the IT intern over internet to my phone. So if someone calls to the IT room the computer will ask to leave a message and then send that message to me.

Comment: @TomasBond Make sure the recording asks if they've tried switching it off and on again.